# How can I turn a plain string into a template string in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

In ES6/ES2015 I am importing a string from a JSON file:

```
import config from './file.json';

config.string; // => "${foo} does things"
```

Now I want to use that string as a template string in another function. [All docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) I can find will do it like

```
(foo) => `${foo} does things`
```

but I could not find anything on how to turn a "plain" string into a template string.

Is this even possible?

Comment: did you get a chance to stumble upon this line Template strings are enclosed by the back-tick (` `) at the link you mentioned , so how about x = "`"+x+"`"  now x should behave like a template string

Comment: I just tried this and did not get it to work, it just inserted backticks. But maybe I don't get what you're trying to say yet.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a template engine, not string interpolation.

Comment: They are called "template literals" btw.

Comment: MDN calls them strings though, so I won't be going to ES6 hell hopefully.